# How do I get notifications when a bot sends a message in Teams?

Tags: node.js, notifications, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I developed a bot for Microsoft Teams using the Microsoft Bot Framework v4 Nodejs SDK (botbuilder-sdk for nodejs). We have implemented the bot in such a way that, when we receive data using a REST API call from one of our CRMs, the data is posted to the channels on Microsoft Teams. However, when I do that, we do not receive a notification on the devices. Has anyone faced such an issue?

I am saving the context state initially. Everytime we receive data from a CRM, I am incrementing the activity id of the message (to send it as a new message and not a reply) and sending it to Microsoft Teams using context.sendActivity().

[image]

When we receive that adaptive card, we do not receive a notification in the activity feed or on any of the devices.

I have gone through all the steps as you described above. I've also gone through the troubleshooting steps. However, it still doesn't give me a notification for the card. However, when I initiate a conversation with the bot, I get a notification when the bot responds.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi4fc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab6uP.png

In this image, I get a notification when I get the TMS Bot started! message. However, I don't get a notification for the next two messages.

Comment: In the Teams app, you can access the settings by tapping the three lines in the upper left corner. From there you can access the Teams notification settings and from the Teams notification settings you can access device-level settings. You might try changing some of those to see if you start getting notifications. Also try having the bot use @ mentions in its messages.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I have all the notifications turned on for my Teams app. Yet, it doesn’t work

Comment: Did you try having the bot @ mention the team? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mentions-to-get-someone-s-attention-in-teams-eb4f059d-320e-454e-b111-03361d4d6855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: OP and I have exchanged a few emails to get this answered. This answer, as a whole, is good information for accomplishing Teams Proactive messaging, in general, but the main answer is in the last section, Simplified Code.**

This is a long answer that covers many areas, simply because I'm not 100% sure I know what kind of notification you aren't receiving.

#### Troubleshooting

- [Troubleshooting Guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshoot-notifications-for-teams-mobile-apps-6d125ac2-e440-4fab-8e4c-2227a52d460c#ID0EAABAAA=Android)

  - Pay special attention to the *many* areas where notifications need to be enabled

    - **In particular, the user may need to "Follow" and/or "Favorite" the channel to receive notifications from it**
- If a user has the desktop app open, they will receive the notification there and will not receive one on their phone unless they have been inactive on the desktop app for 3+ minutes. Otherwise, it's likely a bug in Teams.

#### Chat Notifications

If you've followed the Troubleshooting Guide linked above, your users should receive chat notifications. If not, you can try updating your MS Teams desktop or mobile client. As @KyleDelaney mentioned, it may be helpful to `@` mention users and/or channels

#### Activity Feed Notifications

You can also [create Activity Feed Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed). The gist of it is that you need to:

1. Include `text` and `summary` in the message
2. Include `channelData` that sets `notifications.alert` to true

This code will accomplish that:

```
const msg = MessageFactory.text('my message');
msg.summary = 'my summary';
msg.channelData = {
    notification: {
        alert: true,
    },
};
return await dc.context.sendActivity(msg);
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Note: If your bot *only* creates notifications and doesn't have conversations, you may benefit from [creating a notifications-only bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notification-only).

#### Full Implementation Code

```
import * as adaptiveCard from '../src/adaptiveCard.json';
...
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(adaptiveCard);
const activity = {
    attachments: [card],
    text: 'Test Card',
    summary: 'my summary',
    channelData: {
        notification: {
            alert: true,
        },
    },
};
await turnContext.sendActivity(activity);
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

#### Using the [Teams Extension](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node)

There's a Teams Extension for BobBuilder V4 that's currently in Beta, but seems to accomplish what you need. I believe the reason you weren't getting notifications while using the above is because your bot is creating a new reply chain in the channel and not replying directly to a user. I believe you can do all of this without the extension (by manually editing activity/context properties), but the extension should make it easier.

Here's the code I used to get working notifications within a channel:

In `index.js` (or `app.js`):

```
import * as teams from 'botbuilder-teams';

[...]

// Change existing to use "new teams.TeamsAdapter..."
const adapter = new teams.TeamsAdapter({
    appId: endpointConfig.appId || process.env.microsoftAppID,
    appPassword: endpointConfig.appPassword || process.env.microsoftAppPassword,
});
```

Wherever you're sending the message:

```
import * as teams from 'botbuilder-teams';
import * as adaptiveCard from '../src/adaptiveCard.json';
...
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(adaptiveCard);
const activity = {
    attachments: [card],
    text: 'Test Card',
    summary: 'my summary',
    channelData: {
        notification: {
            alert: true,
        },
    },
};
const adapter = context.adapter as teams.TeamsAdapter;
await adapter.createReplyChain(context, [activity]);
```

#### Simplified Code

OP and I have emailed back and forth a bit and the key issue is that he needed to add the `trustServiceUrl` code from below. Normally, this manifests itself with a 500 error, but in this case, it appears to not create notifications.. After significant testing, here's all you really have to do to send different notifications to different channels. It basically amounts to setting a couple of properties of turncontext.activity and trusting the serviceUrl. No touching activity ID or using the Teams Extension at all. My code below is how I sent messages from Emulator that could then send cards to different Teams channels:

```
public onTurn = async (turnContext: TurnContext) => {
    const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(turnContext);

    const dialogResult = await dc.continueDialog();

    // Route message from Emulator to Teams Channel - I can send "1", "2", or "3" in emulator and bot will create message for Channel
    let teamsChannel;
    switch (turnContext.activity.text) {
        // You can get teamsChannel IDs from turnContext.activity.channelData.channel.id
        case '1':
            teamsChannel = '19:8d60061c3d104exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype';
            break;
        case '2':
            teamsChannel = '19:0e477430ebad4exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype';
            break;
        case '3':
            teamsChannel = '19:55c1c5fb0d304exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0@thread.skype';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (teamsChannel) {
        const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(adaptiveCard);
        const activity = {
            attachments: [card],
            summary: 'my summary',
            text: 'Test Card',
        };
        const serviceUrl = 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/';
        turnContext.activity.conversation.id = teamsChannel;
        turnContext.activity.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
        // This ensures that your bot can send to Teams
        MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
        await turnContext.sendActivity(activity);

    } else {
        [...Normal onTurn Code...]

    await this.conversationState.saveChanges(turnContext);
}
```

*Note: To receive notifications, you and your users **must** follow the channel.*

Comment: Can we do this in v4 using NodeJS?

Comment: Yes. The code above is in Node and V4. I tested all of this and all notifications worked.

Comment: I tried to implement this to send a message.Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit/update your question with additional details? What exactly isn't working? Can you share applicable images? What is the relevant code that you're using? As you can see in my image, I got it working just fine, so it's definitely possible. I just can't help without further details.

Comment: I've made the change to the question.

Comment: I have added additional code. If you don't receive notifications with that, please verify that you went through *all* of the troubleshooting steps. I receive notifications on Desktop, Web, and Mobile versions of Teams. If you still can't get it working, I'd say it's a Teams issue within your organization.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was able to fix the issue with the simplified code and achieve the functionality as desired.

Comment: Where did you find  Teams specific `channelData`?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through all the steps as you described above. I've also gone through the troubleshooting steps. However, it still doesn't give me a notification for the card. However, when I initiate a conversation with the bot, I get a notification when the bot responds.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi4fc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab6uP.png

In this image, I get a notification when I get the TMS Bot started! message. However, I don't get a notification for the next two messages.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into this today. For the sake of trying to replicate this, what Teams Client are you using (Desktop/Web/Mobile)? Is your bot hosted on Azure? How much time passes between receiving "TMS Bot Started" and "New Lead" messages? Do you close the client between messages or leave it open? Do you switch chat channels between messages? Also, you may want to delete this "answer" and add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using the Teams Desktop client, hosted on Azure using the Bot Registration. We do not have a fixed time between the messages. However, during the testing phase, you can say probably 5-10 seconds. We have multiple channels running the same bot. Depending on the data, we post the message to the right channel.

Comment: I see that this is happening when I manually increment the activity id of the context object ( to send the Adaptive Card). When the activity id is automatically generated, I do receive the notification. So I think it's something that I'm probably not running it through the Middleware the correct way.

Comment: That would be my guess. I came across [this teams extension](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node) and am trying to get it working, now. You may find it helpful

Comment: I've updated my answer with a way you can use the Teams Extension. If you're still having issues, it's likely like you said--an issue with your middleware and manually updating the activity id.

Comment: I've implemented the functionality using the Teams Extension. I receive the Adaptive Card, but it still does not give a notification.

Comment: hmm...I am completely unable to replicate this. If you'd like more help troubleshooting, you'll need to share either all of your code or be sure to include all code that might be relevant. If you'd like, you can contact me through my email address in my profile.